# <a href=""> in PHP for Hide link in source view

Tags: php, url, hyperlink, href

I am trying to hide my html file url link when I click on href* its open in pop-up window; normally its working properly but when I doing view source then its showing full URL there:

My HTML script: `<a id="v1" href="Files/file1.html">CLICK HERE</a>`

I already tried bottom script (print* also)

```
<?php
echo("<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=$markme_ddesc\">Tweet this</a>");
?>
```

If anybody have any idea then please help me... ;(

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? I have a feeling that you're approaching this the wrong way. Hiding the link like that is is bad for a number of reasons: * Breaking the convention of being able to see where a link will take you before you click
* No viable fallback in case your JavaScript breaks
* SEO
* etc

Comment: Sorry for my bed English,
Thanks for your comment.

Dear vrutberg,

I know that! this is my demo HTML page which is open in popup window frame and I don't want somebody find link from view source and download my script.

I want to just hide my link with PHP or JAVAScript.


Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if I fully understand the question but could it possibly be because this:

```
window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=$markme_ddesc
```

Should be:

```
window.open('http://www.twitter.com/home?status=$markme_ddesc')
```

I may be completely wrong though.

Comment: Dear Bipolarpants Sorry for my bed English,
Thanks for your comment.

That script only for example and its not work.
I want to just hide my link with PHP or JAVAScript.
Thanks & Regards